# Can't add addresses when geocoding is enabled

Tags: error, 4.7, geocoding

## Steps to reproduce

On the CiviCRM 4.7 / Drupal 7 demo site (demo.civihosting.com):

1. Go to "Administer -> System Settings -> Mapping and Geocoding"
2. Set "Mapping Provider" and "Geocoding Provider" to "Google"
3. Go to "Create New -> Individual"
4. Set "First Name" and "Last Name" to "Test"
5. Open "Address"
6. Set "Country" to "Italy"
7. Click "Save"

## Expected behavior

A new contact should be created, and I should see the summary page for it.

## Actual behavior

I see an error page, reading:

```
Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
Return to home page.

Fatal error: Uncaught CRM_Core_Exception: [0: Transaction integrity error: Expected to find active frame thrown in /home/galleryr/www/demo/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/Transaction/Manager.php on line 107
```

## Analysis

After reading the logs in ConfigAndLog, I found the problem had to do with the empty state/province field. I tracked it down to lines 1060 to 1068 of`CRM/Core/DAO.php`:

`1060     if (
1061       empty($searchValue) ||
1062       trim(strtolower($searchValue)) == 'null'
1063     ) {
1064       // adding this year since developers forget to check for an id
1065       // or for the 'null' (which is a bad DAO kludge)
1066       // and hence we get the first value in the db
1067       CRM_Core_Error::fatal();
1068     }`

Simply deleting these lines seems to resolve the issue. From the comment about "we get the first value in the db", I expected the newly created contact to have an address with state/province id 1, but actually it worked as it should: I gave no state/province, and no state/province is what came out.

Hope that helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the above seems to be fixed recently. Can you please try https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10192 and check if that fixes for you?

Note: The PR is merged in 4.7.20, so it should work without error on this version.

Comment: Yes, that fixes it for me. Thanks @jitendrapurohit!